# Ошибка в вызовах функций

Tags: c

Никогда бы не подумала, что такой вопрос возникнет, и тем не менее возник. Программа вообще большая, но работать не хотела, постоянно выдавала ошибку. Отлаживая, нашла в где происходит ошибка. Если упростить, получится сл.ситуация:

```
void print(int);

void print(int)  
{ 
   int k;     
   printf("%d", k);     
}  
main()   
{ 
   int i;    
   printf("vvedi i");       
   scanf("%d", &i);  
   print(i);   
}
```

Он мне печатает какое-то левое значение. Почему, что не так-то?! Видимо это элементарно, но чёт не соображу.

Comment: p.s. про system("pause") я знаю, не пишу их для экономии места, т.к. суть проблемы не в них:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void print (int k) { 
    printf("%d",k); // и никаких локальных переменных
} 
main () { 
    int i; 
    scanf("%d",&i); 
    print(i); 
}
```

Вроде так.

Что-то с форматирование в комментарии. Пришлось повторить в ответе.

Answer (score 3):

Милая девушка, подумайте, что делает Ваша функция? После вызова она создает локальную переменную k,  потом в функцию printf передается адрес этой переменной. Как Вы думаете, что будет напечатано? Правильно, виртуальный адрес этой самой переменной k в десятичной представлении.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
но всё же, как мне сделать, чтобы значение k было аргументом?  чтобы в main вызывалась ф-я с параметром i
п.с. в printf передаётся значение k.....

Comment: не зразумив

Comment: по-моему, автор предыдущего ответа все очень правильно описал.

Comment: что поменять, чтобы всё работало? чтобы в мэйне после вызова Принта печаталось значение i?

Comment: void print (int k) { printf("%d",k); } // и никаких локальных переменных
    main () { int i; scanf("%d",&i); print(i); }

Вроде так.

Comment: уже все ответили. что не устраивает?

Comment: ребята, с кем вы спорите? вам же сказали - па-ра-докс, страуструп ошибся

Comment: интересно, а Kolllibri симпатичная?

Comment: Gorets, зачем же так? ><

Comment: у меня исходный пример вообще не скомпилировался, а компилятор внятно указал, в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

В `printf` нужно передавать значения, а вы передаете адрес. Вообще попробуйте заменить

```
void print(int)
{ int k; 
  printf("%d", &k); 
}
```

на

```
void print(int k)
{ 
  printf("%d", k); 
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но не то. в коде без &

Comment: Кстати, было с &. Но это сути дела не меняет. Nofate все правильно написал.